# How do I hide my navbar on scroll in just css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my navbar hide when I scroll down without using anything other than html and css with minimal js if possible. I can't provide code until later tonight because of project rules.

Comment: In the future I suggest adding the code to your question at the time you ask it, this will help to ensure you get favorable feed back from the SO community.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because without code it is impossible to provide help. Please open a new question when you have code to display. Also consider being more descriptive regarding the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it is very simple, applied in the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--these are links to the css and little verticle bar icons and also the device width so the navbarand text can work properally at a smaller device width (to an extent)-->
    <title>Parker Aucoin</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="a">
        <div id="home">
            <div id="navbar">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
                    window.onscroll = function() {
                      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
                      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
                        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
                      } else {
                        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-100px";
                      }
                      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
                    } </script>
                <div id="navlinks">
                    <ul>
                        <a href="#portfolio"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
                        <a href="#slideshow"><li>Contact</li></a>
                        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/13392252/parkeraucoin"><li>StackOverflow</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="header">
                    <p>Parker</p>
                </div>
                <div class="header2">
                    <p><span>Aucoin</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="header3">
                    <p>Software Developer</p>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-header">
                    <div id="portfolio">
                        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                        <h3>My GitHub 
                            <a class="github-btn" href="https://github.com/ParkerAucoin/" target="_blank">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.012 8.012 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                  <div id="gallery">
                    <a target="_blank" href="images/portfolio1.jpg">
                      <img src="images/portfolio1.jpg" alt="Forest" width="100" height="200">
                    </a>
                    <div class="desc"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="gallery">
                    <a target="_blank" href="images/portfolio5.jpg">
                      <img src="images/portfolio5.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="100" height="200">
                    </a>
                    <div class="desc"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="gallery">
                    <a target="_blank" href="images/portfolio6.jpg">
                      <img src="images/portfolio6.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
                    </a>
                    <div class="desc"></div>
                  </div>
                </p>
                <div class="spacer">
                <p>
                    <div id="gallery">
                      <a target="_blank" href="images/portfolio2.jpg">
                        <img src="images/portfolio2.jpg" alt="Forest" width="100" height="200">
                      </a>
                      <div class="desc"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="gallery">
                      <a target="_blank" href="images/portfolio3.jpg">
                        <img src="images/portfolio3.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="100" height="200">
                      </a>
                      <div class="desc"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="gallery">
                      <a target="_blank" href="images/portfolio4.jpg">
                        <img src="images/portfolio4.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
                      </a>
                      <div class="desc"></div>
                    </div>
                </p>
                </div>
            <div id="contact">
                <h1 id="contact-header">Contact</h1>
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <div id="slideshow">
                                    <div class="slider">
                                        <div class="slides">
                                            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
                                            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
                                            <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
                                            <div class="slide first">
                                                <img src="images/portfolio1.jpg" alt="image1">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="slide">
                                                <img src="images/portfolio2.jpg" alt="image1">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="slide">
                                                <img src="images/portfolio3.jpg" alt="image1">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="navigarion-auto">
                                                <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                                                <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                                                <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="navigation-manual">
                                            <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
                                            <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
                                            <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                    var counter = 1;
                                    setInterval(function(){
                                        document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
                                        counter++;
                                        if (counter > 3){
                                            counter = 1;
                                        }
                                    }, 5000);
                                    </script>
                            </th>
                        </tr>               
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fugaz+One&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
body{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.8)),url(images/background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
}
#navbar{
    transition: .3s;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
}
#navlinks{
    float: center;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    flex: 1;
    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
}
#navlinks ul{
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navlinks ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 25px;
}
#navlinks ul a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#navlinks ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(255, 100, 52);
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: .3s;
}
#navlinks ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}
.header{
    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1500px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.header p{
font-size: 100px;
}
.header2{
    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: -65px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: -30px;
}
.header2 p{
    font-size: 100px;
}
.header2 span{
    color: rgb(255, 100, 52);
}
.header3{
    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 250px;
}
#contact{
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
    margin: 0;
    top: 100px;
}
#slideshow{
    top: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.slider{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slides{
    width: 500%;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
}
.slides input{
    display: none;
}
.slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: 2s;
}
.slide img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;  
}
.navigation-manual{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.manual-btn{
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 100, 52);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}
.manual-btn:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.manual-btn:hover{
    background: rgb(255, 100, 52);
}
#radio1:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: 0;
}
#radio2:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#radio3:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: -40%;
}
.navigation-auto{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 460px;
}
.navigation-auto div{
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 100, 52);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
}
.navigation-auto div:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 40px;
}
#radio1:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn1{
    background: rgb(255, 100, 52);
}
#radio2:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn2{
    background: rgb(255, 100, 52);
}
#radio3:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn3{
    background: rgb(255, 100, 52);
}
.gallery-header{
    font-family: 'Fugaz One', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20;
}
#portfolio{
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#portfolio h3{
    color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
}
h3 a{
    color: rgb(255, 100, 52);
}
h3 a:hover{
    color: rgb(252, 154, 125);
}
#gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  
  #gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
  }
  
  #gallery img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  
  div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }
th.contact-form{
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    float: center;
}
```